# PostGIS query from three tables

Tags: postgis, query, conditional

I am new in PostGIS and want to learn. I faced the query where I have to find one point in two different layers or table. I created a query like this but it is not giving the desired result:

```
SELECT b.name as "Boroughs_Name", r.name as "Restaurant_Name", l.lsoa11nm as "Lsoa_Name"
FROM italian_restaurants as r, .london_boroughs as b, .london_lsoa as l
WHERE r.name= 'Pasta House' and st_intersects(b.geom, r.geom) or st_intersects(b.geom, l.geom)
```

Comment: could you please clarify what results you expect?

Comment: the expected result should be the restaurant is located on one Lsoa and the Lsoa is located in two Boroughs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try joining the tables:

```
select resturant.*, lsoa.somecolumn, borough.somecolumn
from resturant inner join lsoa on st_intersects(resturant.geom, lsoa.geom)
inner join borough on st_intersects(lsoa.geom, borough.geom)
where resturant.name = 'Pasta house'
```

Comment: Thanks, BERA, I did necessary change in naming but still not working

Comment: still receiving error massage

Comment: No Result: blank output 
select r.name as restaurant_Name, l.lsoa11nm as Lsoa_name, b.name as borough_name
from "Assign05".italian_restaurants as r  inner join "Assign05".london_lsoa as l on st_intersects(r.geom, l.geom)
inner join "Assign05".london_boroughs as b on st_intersects(l.geom, b.geom)
where r.name = 'Pasta house'